# NGinx config for redirecting domain

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have 2 servers on my network:

one linux machine (192.168.0.2) with a website listening on port 8181 for service1.domain.com
one windows machine (192.168.0.3) with a website listening on port 8080 for service2.domain.com

I want to set up an nginx reverse proxy so that I can route requests like so:

```
service1.domain.com --> 192.168.0.2:8181 with host header service1.domain.com

service2.domain.com --> 192.168.0.3:8080 with host header service2.domain.com
```

I have tried with the following config:

```
### General Server Settings             ###

worker_processes  1;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

### Reverse Proxy Listener Definition  ###

http {
 server {
  listen        80;
  server_name       service1.domain.com;
  location / {
   proxy_pass       http://192.168.0.2:8181;
   proxy_set_header     host service1.domain.com;
  }
 }
server {
  listen        80;
  server_name       service2.domain.com;
  location / {
   proxy_pass       http://192.168.0.3:8080;
   proxy_set_header     host service2.domain.com;
  }
 }
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work?

Is there anything blindingly obvious that I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this works fine for me:

```
http {
    server {
        listen        80; 
        server_name       service1.domain.com;
        location / { 
            proxy_pass       http://192.168.0.2:8181;
            proxy_set_header   host  service1.domain.com
        }   
    }
    server {
        listen        80; 
        server_name       service2.domain.com;
        location / { 
            proxy_pass       http://192.168.0.3:8080;
            proxy_set_header     host service2.domain.com;
        }   
    }
}
```

have a try?

Comment: Isn't that exactly the same? I also just realised that the fact the box is behind a router that is forwarding the port to it so the external IP isn't the same as the nginx box IP? Does that matter? Setting the listen to the external IP gives me: The requested address is not valid in its context)

Comment: Yes, the server part is the same. ngnix listen at 80 then distribute the request to `192.168.0.2:8181` and `192.168.0.3:8080` according to host name.

Comment: Just use the config in you question, what happened?

Comment: You can use `ping` or `telnet` to debug the router.

Comment: There is a missing semicolon at the end of the first proxy_set_header.